# QueryDSL JPASQLQuery inner join error

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to convert the following jpa query to QueryDSL.

```
select 
    NEW aaa.dto.UserDto(s.username, i.mailaddress, s.enabled, i.lastlogin, i.lastlogout, i.loginErrorcount) 
from 
    SUsers s, UserInfo i 
where 
     s.username = i.username
```

query dsl test code is following.

```
@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    JPASQLQuery query = new JPASQLQuery(em, new H2Templates());
    QSUsers qsUser = QSUsers.sUsers;
    QUserInfo qInfo = QUserInfo.userInfo;
    List<UserDto> dtos = query.from(qsUser, qInfo).where(qsUser.username.eq(qInfo.username))
            .list(ConstructorExpression.create(UserDto.class, qsUser.username, qInfo.mailaddress, qsUser.enabled, qInfo.lastlogin, qInfo.lastlogout, qInfo.loginErrorcount));
    assertThat(dtos.size(), not(0));
}
```

Then following error occurred.

> SQL Error: 42001, SQLState: 42001
>       "SELECT SUSERS.USERNAME, USERINFO.MAILADDRESS, SUSERS.ENABLED, USERINFO.LASTLOGIN, USERINFO.LASTLOGOUT, USERINFO.LOGINERRORCOUNT
>       FROM USERS SUSERS, USERINFO
>       WHERE SUSERS.USERNAME = USERINFO. ";expected "identifier"; SQL statement:

I'm not sure why right side `identifire` is missing.

Comment: Update QueryDSL 3.6.1 to 3.6.2 then work fine.

Comment: please put the right answer !!!